# Unable to create org.apache.spark.sql.Row with scala.None value since Spark 2.X

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Since Spark 2.X unable to create org.apache.spark.sql.Row with scala.None value (it was possible for Spark 1.6.X)

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.None$ is not a valid external type for schema of string
```

Reproducible example:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

spark.createDataFrame(
  sc.parallelize(Seq(Row(None))),
  StructType(Seq(StructField("v", StringType, true)))
).first
```

Gist:
https://gist.github.com/AleksandrPavlenko/bef1c34458883730cc319b2e7378c8c6

Looks like it was changed in [SPARK-15657](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15657) (not sure, still trying to prove it)

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior as described in [SPARK-19056](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19056) (*Row encoder should accept optional types*):

> This is intentional. Allowing `Option` in `Row` is never documented and brings a lot of troubles when we apply the encoder framework to all typed operations. Since Spark 2.0, please use `Dataset` for typed operation/custom objects